# How to revert from node.js 4.0.0 to 0.12.x?

Tags: node.js, macos, ionic-framework

The current node.js 4.0.0 [breaks some ionic workflows](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/584). How to revert to 0.12.x on OS X? My 4.0.0 is installed from the [Mac OS X Installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular [gist here](https://gist.github.com/TonyMtz/d75101d9bdf764c890ef) to uninstall node. Then I would install [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash
```

With **nvm** installed you can install whatever version of node you want, e.g. `nvm install v12.0.0`, then to make that the default you can `nvm alias default v12.0.0`.

You could also reinstall 4.0.0 using nvm with `nvm install v4.0.0`, and then if you want to play around with the newest version just `nvm use v4.0.0`, then when you don't want to risk it breaking anything, revert to an older version. I didn't bother with **nvm** for quite a while, but now I highly recommend it. Have a read through the repo README and get acquainted with it. You won't look back!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nvm`, `n` or compile it yourself.

For example `n 0.12` does the job. You can get it via `npm install n -g`